# Can I update from iOS 5 to iOS 6 on iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

I don't want to update to iOS 7 on this iPhone 4 and since I'm borrowing it from a friend, I don't want to jailbreak it either.

It's not a matter of downgrading to iOS 6, it's still an upgrade since I'm currently running iOS 5.1, I just need to know where to find the update and how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Apple supported way to update an iOS devices OS except to the latest current OS release that runs on that device (or a beta OS, if it is strictly a test device and you are a registered developer).  Apple no longer signs (which includes vouching for the security of) any earlier OS releases (except for old devices, such as an iPhone 3GS).

Comment: Thanks, HotPaw. That's what I keep reading. Very annoying. Thanks for responding.

Comment: This one should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, no.

Apple, last I heard, did not keep old downloads of previous firmware upgrades available for download.

However if you wish to live dangerously other places do. I would imagine it's not strictly legal but there are a number of websites that keep them available for download, for example iosindex.com has a list of firmware downloads that looks fairly complete.

NOTE I am *NOT* endorsing this place, I've never used it and can't vouch for the safety of the firmware upgrades they have available. So proceed with caution.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I find this whole thing pretty annoying. They do realize that not all devices can run these crazy new updates. Anyway, guess I'll start asking around for anyone who can vouch for any of these websites. -Sandra

Comment: I've been working with and supporting Macs since about 1990. One thing you get used to is that Apple does things differently and often in an annoying and inconvenient fashion. You either develop a a "resigned to it" philosophy or you give up, post a tantrum to Macintouch.com about how Apple has betrayed you one time too many and journey off to the Windows side of things. As you might imagine I am in the former category...

Comment: The big boys make the rules, we begrudgingly follow. Gotcha. ;) Thanks again. -S

Comment: Actually, that site is legal. It really is hosted on Apple's servers.

Comment: The problem is not having the software, but the installing of it (and getting your device activated after that).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you good news!
Yes, it **IS** possible. Download redsn0w. Get your IPSW from somewhere like ipsw.me (yes, it's legal). Then, modify the IPSW (this part is sorta shakey, Google it. I prefer to keep the baseband the same, but that removes service). Then, using redsn0w, boot your iphone in Pwned DFU mode. Then, go to itunes and option + click the restore button. Select your modified ipsw, and downgrade! Sorta complex.

Comment: @bmike Sorry, just realized this is old. Should I remove this?

Comment: More then old how do you expect iTunes to sign the update now?

Comment: @iskra No. No one is signing the firmware. That's the whole point. It's a bootROM exploit. (limera1n)

Comment: When did you do that without SHSH blobs? And how could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @iskra I can't go too much farther, but basically if you modify the IPSW (e.g add files, keep current baseband), and boot from Pwned DFU mode (only for [A4](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/A4) devices), and choose your custom IPSW, it works.

Comment: and every time you boot your device Redsn0w will be required?

Comment: @iskra nope. No jailbreak required, only bootstrapping. Downside is either broken cellular connection, or something else (I'm trying to work out how to add a file to an IPSW).